# how to wrap all li element inside ul element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent2">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<div class="all"></div>
```

I am using following jQuery code to get all `li` elements of  `.parent` class and want to show that all `li` elements to div class called `.all`.

```
<script>
$(".all").prepend("<ul>");
$( ".parent li" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(".all").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
});
$(".all").prepend("</ul>");
</script>
```

now it's adding to `.all` div class but `<ul>` and `</ul>` element is adding above the `li` elements but it's should be wrap the all `li` elements.

**what I want for e.g:**

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    res of the li..
</ul>
```

**but showing:**

```
<ul></ul>
<li>one</li>
res of the li..
```

Comment: You don't have any element which contains `all` class.

Comment: Updated, it was mistake.

Comment: `$('.all').append($('.parent'))` check this, it will append including ul to .all class element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For append elements inside the `<ul>` just use `find()` over the `<div>` element with class `.all` to find the new appended `<ul>` tag, and then add alls the `<li>` on it:

```
<script>
$(".all").append("<ul>");
var ul = $(".all").find("ul");

$( ".parent li" ).each(function( index )
{
    ul.append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
});
</script>
```

You can check the next working example:

```js
$(".all").append("<ul>");
var ul = $(".all").find("ul");

$( ".parent li" ).each(function( index )
{
    ul.append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent2">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<div class="all"></div>
```

Comment: can I remove the first li element which is adding?

Comment: You want to remove this one `<li><a href="">one</a></li>` after you added it or you directly don't want to add it?

Comment: No, Now all the li elements is adding to the `.all` class. that's good. But I want to add all except the first one.

Comment: You can replace this line: `$(".all").find("ul").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");` for this one: `if (index != 0) $(".all").find("ul").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");`. Check if is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".all").prepend("<ul>");
$( ".parent li" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(".all ul").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
});
$(".all").prepend("</ul>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent2">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<div class="all"></div>
```

**Your code**

`$(".all").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");`

**Should be changed**

`$(".all ul").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");`

Answer (score 1):

The jquery code can be rewritten like this:

```js
$(".all").append("<ul>");

$( ".parent li" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(".all ul").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent2">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<div class="all"></div>
```

You're getting the problem because you're using `prepend` method as a wrong way.

`.prepend` is used to add an element to the selector. Since you added `ul` tag using `$(".all").prepend("<ul>");`. You don't need to add this tag again (`$(".all").prepend("</ul>");`).

Also, you're trying to append new `li` tag inside the div tag (`.all` element). It can be fixed by adding `ul` inside the selector `$(".all ul")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prependTo()`

```js
$(".all").prepend("<ul class='new'>");
$( ".parent li" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(".all").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
});
$(".all li").prependTo(".new");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
    <ul class="parent2">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<div class="all"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a new `<ul>` or use loops. Simply duplicate the existing `<ul>`, find its `<a>` elements, and `.unwrap()`  them:

```js
$(".parent")
    .clone()               //Duplicate the <ul>
    .appendTo(".all")      //Put the copy in the <div>
    .find("a")             //Find all of its <a> elements
    .contents().unwrap();  //Strip the <a> tag, but leave the text
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href=""></a>
  <ul class="parent">
    <li><a href="">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="">five</a></li>
    <li><a href="">six</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href=""></a>
  <ul class="parent2">
    <li><a href="">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="">four</a></li>
    <li><a href="">five</a></li>
    <li><a href="">six</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<div class="all"></div>
```